# Como hago para que cada celda me genere un número aleatorio, actualmente los genera por filas

Tags: javascript, html

Ya me habían ayudado antes para este ejercicio en la página pero solo obteniendo números aleatorios en las filas, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo con cada celda
el código es el siguiente:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Trabajo Quiz </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="filas" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="columnas" /><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="ObtenerArregloAleatorio()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
  <script>
    function ObtenerArregloAleatorio() {
      var filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
      var columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);
      var numero = filas * columnas;
      document.write(" <table border='2'>  ");

      for (i = 1; i <= filas; i++) {
        aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
        if (aleatorio < 100) {
          aleatorio = aleatorio * 10;
        }
        document.write(" <tr>  ");
        for (j = 1; j <= columnas; j++) {
          document.write("<td>" + aleatorio + "</td>");
        }
        document.write(" </tr>  ");
      }
      document.write(" </table>  ");
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu script tienes 2 ciclos `for`; con uno creas las filas y con el otro las celdas de la tabla.

Basta con mover la creacion del numero aleatorio al ciclo `for` en el que construyes las celdas, en lugar de cuando construyes las filas; de este modo, un numero aleatorio es creado cada vez que se construye una celda y se le asigna a esa celda, en cada nueva iteracion crea otro numero y lo inserta en su respectiva celda.

En tu codigo original, generabas tu numero aleatorio cuando creabas la fila de la tabla, luego de esto empezabas a crear las celdas, pero el numero se mantenia igual ya que seguias recorriendo el 2do `for` con el mismo numero aleatorio que creaste antes de entrar al ciclo, por tanto se aplicaba el mismo a toda la fila y cambiaba hasta avanzar a la siguiente fila y generar un nuevo numero.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Trabajo Quiz </title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="filas" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="columnas" /><br>
  <button type="button" onClick="ObtenerArregloAleatorio()">Crear Tabla</button><br>
  <script>
    function ObtenerArregloAleatorio() {
      var filas = parseInt(document.getElementById("filas").value);
      var columnas = parseInt(document.getElementById("columnas").value);
      var numero = filas * columnas;
      document.write(" <table border='2'>  ");

      for (i = 1; i <= filas; i++) {
        document.write(" <tr>  ");
        for (j = 1; j <= columnas; j++) {
          var aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000));
          if (aleatorio < 100) {
            aleatorio = aleatorio * 10;
          }
          document.write("<td>" + aleatorio + "</td>");
        }
        document.write(" </tr>  ");
      }
      document.write(" </table>  ");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: probando el algoritmo vi que hay la posibilidad de que el numero aleatorio que se genero sea menor a 100 y necesito que el numero llegue a ser un numero comprendido entre 100 y 999, como logro que solo obtenga números entre 100 y 999?

Comment: Tendrias que buscar otra manera de tratar esos casos en que el numero aleatorio sea menor a 10 en realidad, ya que todo numero aleatorio menor a 10 te dara un resultado menor a 100 al multiplicarlo; tambien tienes que tomar en consideracion el caso en que el numero aleatorio sea 0; podrias intentar escribir otras condiciones adicionales para tratar esos escenarios

Comment: ya lo solucione, lo hice sumándole al numero aleatorio 100 en caso de que fuera menor a 100, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que es sencillo, prueba poniendo la línea de generación del random dentro del for de las columnas (j).

Me cuentas cómo te va.

Un abrazo

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [answer]

Comment: El usuario al que le respondes también es relativamente nuevo, como tú. Por favor, intenta ser un poco más explícito en tu respuesta para que sea más clara y fácil de seguir. Yo la entiendo, no sabemos si el OP también.

Comment: Gracias por su guía.